# Is $f(z) =\sin \frac {\pi} z$ bounded in any nbd of zero and related queries

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

$f$ is a bounded function defined on $\Bbb{C} - 0$ such that $f(\frac 1n)=0$ for all positive integer $n$. Then
(a) $f(0)=0$
(b) $f(z) =0$ for all $z$
(c) $f$ is bounded in any neighbourhood of   $0 $
(d) $f(z) $ may assume all complex values except possibly one
**Try**
Considering the function $f(z) =\sin \frac {\pi} z$ option (a) and (b) is discarded. Now the zeroes of $f(z) =\sin \frac {\pi} z$ are $\frac 1n$ having limit point $0$. So $f(z) =\sin \frac {\pi} z$ has essential singularity at $0$.so it cannot be entire hence option (d) discarded. So I think option (c) true. But I can't prove this option. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this question assumes that $f$ has any "nice" properties, e.g. it doesn't need to be holomorphic. Thus, you need a bit better proof. In fact $\sin\frac{\pi}{z}$ *does* assume all complex values, so it cannot serve as a counterexample of (d). (It is also not bounded on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, so it cannot serve as a counterexample for *anything* here.) However, you are right: $f$ must be bounded in any neighbourhood of zero. (Didn't you assume up-front that $f$ was bounded on the entire set $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$?)

Comment: Ya, you are right. The first line of the problem says $f$ is bounded.